# eclipse no found repositories(nexus)

Tags: eclipse, nexus

В работе разработчики несколько раз сталкивались с проблемой, что при разработке в среде Eclipse некоторые прокси-репозитории становятся недоступны. В связи с этим появляется необходимость просмотра их исходных URL-адресов.

Прошу проконсультировать, как разработчики в интерфейсе нексуса могут узнать исходные url прокси-репозитории

[image: no found]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

[мне это кажется поможет](https://coderoad.ru/30194589/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-Nexus)

[на английском объясняется настройка](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/npm-registry)

1. Репозиторий прокси
   Является repository with the type proxy, также известный как репозиторий прокси, представляет собой репозиторий, связанный с удаленным репозиторием.
   Любой запрос для компонента проверяется в отношении локального содержимого репозитория прокси. Если локальный компонент не найден, запрос пересылается в удаленный репозиторий. Затем компонент извлекается и сохраняется локально в диспетчере репозитория, который действует как кеш.
   Последующие запросы для того же компонента затем выполняются из локального хранилища, поэтому устраняются пропускная способность сети и временные накладные расходы для извлечения компонента из удаленного репозитория.

По умолчанию диспетчер репозитория поставляется со следующими настроенными репозиториями прокси:

а). maven-central - Прокси-репозиторий обращается к Центральному репозиторию, ранее известному как Maven Central.

б). nuget.org-proxy - Этот репозиторий прокси получает доступ к галерее NuGet. Это репозиторий компонентов по умолчанию, используемый средством управления пакетами nuget, используемым для разработки .Net.

2. Хостинг-репозиторий
   A repository with the type hosted, также известный как размещенный репозиторий, представляет собой хранилище, в котором хранит компоненты в менеджере репозитория как авторитетное местоположение для этих компонентов.

По умолчанию диспетчер репозитория поставляется со следующими настроенными размещенными репозиториями:

а). maven-релизы - Этот размещенный репозиторий использует maven2 repository format с политикой версии выпуска. Это , предназначенный для размещения в репозитории, где ваша организация публикует внутренние версии. Вы также можете использовать этот репозиторий для сторонних компонентов, которые недоступны во внешних репозиториях и поэтому не могут быть получены через настроенный репозиторий прокси.

б). maven-snapshots - Использует maven2 repository format с политикой версии моментального снимка. Он предназначен для хранилища, в котором ваша организация публикует внутренние версии разработки, также известные как моментальные снимки.

с). nuget-hosting -. Это репозиторий, в котором ваша организация может публиковать внутренние выпуски в репозитории с помощью NuGet repository format.

Comment: спасибо, изучаю. 
А  узнать исходные url прокси-репозитории, т.е 
url - этот http://nexus.szz.ru/content/repositories/betty9415/  он и есть ? 
Или какой нужен url ???

Comment: не смогу подсказать боюсь запутать ещё больше .. посмотри это [https://coderoad.ru/3770125/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-sbt-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-maven-Nexus]

Comment: привет разобрались, что есть недоступные репо-и. это связано с закрытием/удалением/перемещением оригинала.
много  репозиториев имеет статус автоблок с недоступностью источника.
Буду делать список:
URL nexus, URL оригинала, статус, анализ причины почему недоступен
а url оригинала это 
"http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/bab/update-site/R0.10.0/indigo/"  это указано в нексус remote storage location если это url оригинала с помощью какого клиента смотреть ?